Why am I getting this error, “Entry Point Not Found Error (dxgi.dll)?”
I have this annoying error, that I don't understand at all:

Entry Point Not Found
The procedure entry point CreateDXGIFactory2 could not be located in the dynamic link library dxgi.dll.

Is this DirectX related? or GPU driver related? how can I fix it?
Program that throws this error: SketchUP.exe v2024
Already installed:

latest Nvidia drivers for GPU

latest DirectX v11

latest DirectX Runtime Components

and all of these:



Workaround: downgrade of program to v2023

Read the SketchUp Hardware and Software Requirements:

SketchUp 2021 - With the release of SketchUp 2021 we’ve removed
support for MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra) as well as Windows 7 and 8. We
have added support for MacOS 11.0 (Big Sur).

This means formally starting from version 2021 this application isn't supported for Windows 7.
Theoretically you will not be able to solve this problem because of the SketchUp version v2024 was compiled with a different version of DirectX existing on the Windows 7.
This is why you getting

Entry Point Not Found (dxgi.dll)


You can try some suggestion from the Sketchup community forum:

SU 2024 and Windows 7
Uninstalled All Traces of Sketchup - To install 2024 and 2023

